# Mongodb $loopkup: Lookup only those documents which satisfy a condition

Tags: python, mongodb, api, aggregation-framework

I have two collections, `tasks` and `users`. The `users` collection has 3 important fields `user_id`, `parent_user_id` and `details`. `tasks` has `user_id` field which connects it with `users`.

The requirement of an API is to attach the relevant `users.details` with the `tasks` document and it has to be matched with `parent_user_id`. For this I am using `$lookup` to match and put the relevant `user_details`, but since sometimes the `parent_user_id` can be different to the `user_id` I have to use 2 lookups.

The first `$lookup` attaches the `parent_user_id` for the `user_id` in the `tasks` collection and the next `$lookup` attaches the `details` using the extracted `parent_user_id`.

My current pipeline:

```
[
{
    '$lookup': {
        'from': 'users', 
        'let': {
            'uid': '$user_id', 
            'pid': '$project_id'
        }, 
        'pipeline': [
            {
                '$match': {
                    '$expr': {
                        '$and': [
                            {
                                '$eq': [
                                    '$project_id', '$$pid'
                                ]
                            }, {
                                '$eq': [
                                    '$user_id', '$$uid'
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                '$project': {
                    '_id': 0, 
                    'parent_user_id': 1
                }
            }
        ], 
        'as': 'parent_info'
    }
}, {
    '$replaceRoot': {
        'newRoot': {
            '$mergeObjects': [
                {
                    '$arrayElemAt': [
                        '$parent_info', 0
                    ]
                }, '$$ROOT'
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        'parent_info': 0
    }
}, {
    '$lookup': {
        'from': 'users', 
        'let': {
            'pid': '$project_id', 
            'uid': '$parent_user_id'
        }, 
        'pipeline': [
            {
                '$match': {
                    '$expr': {
                        '$and': [
                            {
                                '$eq': [
                                    '$project_id', '$$pid'
                                ]
                            }, {
                                '$eq': [
                                    '$user_id', '$$uid'
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                '$project': {
                    '_id': 0, 
                    'details': 1
                }
            }
        ], 
        'as': 'user_info'
    }
}, {
    '$replaceRoot': {
        'newRoot': {
            '$mergeObjects': [
                {
                    '$arrayElemAt': [
                        '$user_info', 0
                    ]
                }, '$$ROOT'
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        'user_info': 0, 
        'project_id': 0
    }
}
```

]

This is working fine. The issue is most of the times the `parent_user_id` is same as `user_id` so I can just get the `details` in the first lookup itself and totally ignore the second lookup, but I am unable to acheive it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding `is_same_user` field in the `$addFields` stage and then filter out those users with the `$match` stage. Here is a full query:

```js
db.tasks.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "let": {
        "uid": "$user_id",
        "pid": "$project_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$project_id",
                    "$$pid"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "is_same_user": {
              "$eq": [
                "$user_id",
                "$$uid"
              ]
            },
            "lookup_user_id": {
              "$ifNull": [
                "$parent_user_id",
                "$user_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$or": [
                {
                  "$and": [
                    {
                      "$eq": [
                        "$is_same_user",
                        true
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "$eq": [
                        "$user_id",
                        "$$uid"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$lookup_user_id",
                    "$$uid"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "parent_user_id": 1,
            "details": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "user_info"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$user_info",
              0
            ]
          },
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "user_info": 0,
      "project_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here is a link to MongoDB playground to see the query work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LZlM9FnVs5U